# Flatten in simple feedforward networks

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am working on the CIFAR10 dataset and came across this example in Keras, using data augmentation:

https://keras.io/examples/cifar10_cnn/

The example uses CNN. I want to implement just a simple feedforward network, not CNN.
Therefore, in order for my simple model to "work", I have to add "model.Flatten()" before the output layer, in order to have consistency in the data shapes.

However, I have seen using the Flatten() only in CNNs.

I believe that it can be used in simple feedforward networks, but am I missing something?

Below is the model's code that I want to use with the keras example.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(layer_size, input_shape=x_train.shape[1:], activation = "relu")
model.add(Dense(128, activation = "relu"))      
model.add(Dense(64, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation = "softmax"))
model.summary()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should `Flatten` your input:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(Dense(layer_size,activation = "relu")
model.add(Dense(128, activation = "relu"))      
model.add(Dense(64, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dense(10, activation = "softmax"))
model.summary()
```

`Flatten` flattens an `n` dimensional tensor into a `1` dimensional tensor. For example a `2x2` grayscale image becomes 1 dimesnional:

```
[[255, 127   ],
 [154,   123]]
```

becomes

```
[255, 127, 154, 123]
```

This way your input color image (3 dimensional , `[width, height, channels]`) will also become 1 dimensional and fit into a `Dense` layer.